# Gas combi boiler raditator flushing to clear dirt

Tags: heating, boiler, central-heating, radiator

When I flushed my radiator, I have noticed that there is lots of sludge in the water.

In order to remove the sludge from the heating system, I would like to

- Turn off the Worcester gas boiler
- Open the pressure valve of the boiler so that water flows into the system
- Open the radiator drain valve to let the water flow until it is clear of sludge

Please suggest if there will be any issue in the above process of draining the water continuously while pressuring the system through the boiler.

I have searched online and couldn't find anyone doing this method of flushing and wondering if it will cause any problem to the boiler.

Comment: Be sure to add a good quality corrosion inhibitor as the final stage. The system should not be left with plain water in over the long term or parts will corrode - it's that corrosion which introduces air into the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no response to my question, I took a chance and tried as below and there was no problem, I have cleared all the sludge.

- Turn off the Worcester gas boiler
- Open the pressure valve of the boiler so that water flows into the system
- Open the radiator drain valve to let the water flow until it is clear of sludge

  Maybe not as efficient as power flushing but it is an easy and cheap procedure